# T-SQL: advise on copying data across to another database

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I need advise on copying daily data to another server.

Just to give you an image of the situation, I will explain a  little. there are workstations posting transactions to 2 database servers (`DB1` and `DB2`). These db servers hosted on 2 separate physical servers and are linked. Daily transactions are 50.000 for now but will increase soon. There might be days some workstations down (operational but cannot post data) and transactions posted after a few days.

So, what I do is I run a query on those 2 linked servers. The daily query output contains ~50.000 records with minimum 15 minutes fetching time as linked servers have performance problems.I will create a SP and schedule it to run 2AM in the morning.

My concern starts from here, the output will be copied across to another data warehouse (DW). This is our client's special land, I do not know much about. This DW will be linked onto these db servers to make it possible to send the data (produced by my stored procedure) across.

Now, what would you do to copy the data across:

1. Create a dummy table on `DB1` to copy stored procedure output on the same server so make sure it is available and we do not need to rerun stored procedure again. Then client retrieves it later.
2. Use "select into" statement to copy the content to remote DW table. I do not know what happens with this one during fetching and sending data across to DW. Remember it takes ~15 mins to fetch the data by my stored procedure.
3. post the data (retrieved by stored procedure) with xml file through ftp.
4. Please tell me if there is a way of setting an alert or notification on jobs.

I just want to take precautions so it will be easier to track when something goes wrong.

Any advice is appreciated very much. Thank you. Oz.

Comment: There are too many unknown factors to give a definitive answer to this question. Are the transactions posted by the workstations all identical? If they are and they are stored in a single table then I'd like to understand why it take 15+ mins to pull 50k records. Are the linked servers on the same LAN? If not are the two servers and the clients connected via vpn? If so what speed connection is between them?

The setup would very much dictate the best approach but there are many options available for moving data between servers.

Answer (score 0):

When it comes to coping data in SQL Server you need to look at High Availability Solutions, depending on the version and edition of your SQL Server you will have different options.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190202(v=sql.105).aspx

If you need just to move data for specific tables you can have options like SSIS job or SQL Server Replication.

If you are looking to have all tables in a given databases copied to another server you should use [Log Shipping](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187103(v=sql.110).aspx). Which allows you to copy entire content of source database to another location. Because this is done of smaller interval the your load will be distributed over larger period of time instead of having large transaction running at once.

Another great alternative is [SQL Server Replication](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms151198.aspx). This option will capture transaction on the source and push them to the target. This model requires publisher *(source)*, distributor *(can be source or another db)* and subscriber *(target)*.

Also you can create SSIS job that runs on frequent basis and just moves specified amount of data.